# How to save and concatenate plotly express images in a loop?

Tags: python, loops, plotly

I made a loop that creates different figures using `plotly` express. The problem is I do not know how to save those figures. I want to save them in every loop.

The code:

```py
import plotly.express as px

for i in range(0, max(df['frame']), 30):
    df1 = df[df['frame'].between(i, i + 30)] 
    df2 = df[df['frame'].between(i - 30, i)]
    df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2[df2.id.isin(df1.id)]], axis=0)

    # Here creates the fig
    fig = px.line(df1, x='smooth_y', y='smooth_x', color='id') 

    # I do NOT want to show it, I want to save it!
    fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save the image, you use the `write_image()` method. Something like this:

```py
fig.write_image("path/to/your/fig1.png")
```

Take a look at the [official documentation](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/).

Comment: I tried fig.write_image and it works. My problem is I want to save them in every loop and it only saves the last one.

Comment: Update the question with what you are trying now, and I will help you. It is probably just a matter of moving the `write_image()` call inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create an empty list, then append your figures to it.

```
import plotly.express as px

res = []
for i in range(10):
  # Here, generate your dataframe df1
  fig = px.line(df1)
  res.append(fig)
```

Then access your figures this way :

```
res[0].show() # Shows first figure
res[1].show() # Shows second figure
```

Comment: Thank you John!! It is an interesting way of saving my results. I tried it and it works! My question is: How could I save everything inside "res" in a folder? Is there any way to do that, so that I can have all my pictures in a folder? Because my problem is I still can not save all this pictures